# Entry-wise norms of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the use of entry-wise p-norm for $p>2$? I understand that $p=1$ and $p=2$ could be used as upper-bounds for maximum eigenvalue or spectral norm of positive matrices at least. But what properties do entry-wise norms have especially for $p=4$?

Comment: How interested are you in $p=4$, versus some fixed arbitrary $p > 2$? It seems like you are asking a question where someone might give you a magnificent answer for say, $p = 8$ and then you might not be interested since it doesn't generalize to $p = 4$. Are you specifically looking for answers of the form "For $p > 2$ the following holds", and/or "For $p = 4$ the following holds"?

Comment: These norms fail to be submultiplicative for $p > 2$, but are submultiplicative for $p \leq 2$.  I think that Hölder's inequality might give you something useful here.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in p=4... but it would be good to know if there is a general use in them. Why do we define them. Do they have a relation with eigenvalues in general? The two-norm squared is the sum of squares of eigenvalues... can we say anything like that about other entry-wise norms? But again, I'm specifically interested in p=4. I have seen that the entry-wise $4$-norm is an upper bound for the maximum eigenvalue if the matrix is symmetric. Is that true?

Comment: @JamesSmithson I think I'm the one who said that.  In retrospect I'm not sure that this is true for the entrywise $4$-norm.  It is certainly true for all induced $p$-norms and Schatten $p$-norms, though.